# como guardar (cin) datos de registros y clases anidadas? c++

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos, clase

Tengo que hacer un inventario de productos, tengo la clase `product` la cuál contiene todos los datos que dicho producto debe llevar, como muestro a continuación:

```
class Product
{
private:

struct 
{
char BarCode[13];
char Name[30];
float Weight;
float WholesalePrice;
float RetailPrice;
int Availability;

}ProductInfo;

public:
char getBarCode;
char getName;
float getWeight;
float getWholesalePrice;
float getRetailPrice;
int getAvailability;

char setBarCode(const char&);
char setName(const char&) ;
float setWeight(const float&);
float setWholesalePrice(const float&);
float setRetailPrice(const float&);
int setAvailability(const float&);
};
```

Tengo otra clase `date` para fechas como por ejemplo la fecha en que entro un producto como muestro a continuación:

```
class Date
{
private:

int year;
int month;
int day;

public:
int getYear();
int getMonth();
int getDay();

void setYear(const int&);
void setMonth(const int&);
void setDay(const int&);

};
```

Por ultimo tengo una clase `inventory` la cual debería tener toda la colección de productos ,como muestro a continuación:

```
class Inventory
{

private:
Product NewIn;
Product NewOut;
Date InDate;
Date OutDate;

public:
Product getNewIn;
Product getNewOut;
Date getInDate;
Date getOutDate;

Product setNewIn(const Product&);
Product setNewOut(const Product&);
Date setInDate(const Date&);
Date setOutDate(const Date&);
};
```

En el main defino un arreglo de 600 entradas del tipo `inventory` `Inventory NewProduct[600]` al momento de solicitar el código de barras al usuario:

```
    cout<<"INSERT PRODUCT BARCODE:  "<<endl;
    cin>>BC;
    NewProduct[i].setNewIn(BC).BarCode;
    i++;
```

En la linea debajo del cin me da el error `"no matching function for call Inventory::setNewIn(const char&)"`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para guardar el valor código de barras en su lugar? ¿Es correcto lo que hice?

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error dice que no existe una función setNewIn que reciba como parémetro `const char&`, porque tu función setNewIn recibe `const Product&` un producto. Es decir, le estas pasando una cadena de caracteres, cuando la función espera un producto.

No tengo toda la información de tu código, así que esto que te digo ahora es un poco a ciegas.

Si, por lo que entiendo, quieres guardar un producto en `NewIn` con los métodos que ya has definido, deberías crear un producto auxiliar, darle a este producto los valores que quieres introducir en `NewIn` y pasarlo como parámetro a `setNewIn`.

Si lo que quieres es modificar solo el código de barras de un objeto concreto, no puedes hacer `.BarCode` porque es un atributo privado (Ojo, que eso es un error grave). En el caso de que quieras modificar el código de barras del producto que esta en `NewIn` tendrías que hacer algo así:

`NewProduct[i].setNewIn( NewProduct[i].getNewIn().setBarCode(BC) );`

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> ```
> no matching function for call Inventory::setNewIn(const char&)
> ```

> ```
> no existe ninguna función para llamar `Inventory::setNewIn(const char&)`
> ```

Esto indica que estás llamando a la función `setNewIn` sobre un objeto de tipo `Inventory` pasando como parámetro un dato de tipo `const char&` (referencia constante a carácter). Esto sucede en esta línea:

```
NewProduct[i].setNewIn(BC).BarCode;
```

Sabemos que `NewProduct[i]` debe arrojar un ojbeto de tipo `Inventory` y supongo que la variable `BC` debe ser de tipo `char`. El problema es que la función `setNewIn` no acepta un `char` como entrada si no un `Product`:

```
Product setNewIn(const Product&);
```

Una posible solución es permitir que `Product` sea construible con un `char`:

```
class Product
{
    // …
public:
    Product(char BC) : getBarCode{BC} {}
    // …
};
```

De esta manera al pasar un `char` a `Inventory::setNewIn` primero se construirá un `Product` y luego se pasará a la función (puedes ver un ejemplo de esto en [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY1BC4JAEIXPu79iIEg9FJ1VukSBF5OwQxAsMi61kLOyrkWEv91WkKVrp3l8vHkftu3qhjiOC0X46GsJqdKdNbJqtpy70KOFwujaXf7hbI4h3isTceYI62wdx6h7C2kKQhSnfVlexOGc78rsmAsx4eBKQcLZwIfEr2b0lGS1ef/sQidtLl8Zhaip8@YltP/LmJG2NwStFyuy0FSKwmhSej8o11Brrw4wiByZ3zcJH8bxCw)).